# Can I use <QtSql> in C4Droid?

Tags: android, c++, qt

Have anybody managed to compile a c++ file with `"#include <QtSql>"` directive?

As soon as I include that directive, I get this compile error:

```
Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated. /data/user/0/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/temp.c:3:17:fatal error: QtSql: No such file or directory
#include <QtSql>
       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Any ideas for enabling QtSql (specifically SqlLite in C4Droid)?

Comment: show your .pro, please

Comment: Add `QT += sql` to your .pro file.

Comment: It was a single .cpp file for testing purposes, so no .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

After emailing the creator, I decided to reinstall GCC plugin and enabled carefully all Qt options. It worked.